# How to return value from json object to another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

Using Nodejs, Express and Postgresql in my web application. From my code I taking from database last record but I would like to use this record as value to calculate BMI

I've tried to create new function for calculate BMI but I think first I need to take json object from getLastRecord and return this as value then do some calculation and return as json object in renderMainPage. Am I right? Not sure if I follow correct way

```
app.get(
  "/",
  getLastRecord,
  renderMainPage
);

function getLastRecord(req, res, next) {
  pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
    const query = "SELECT * FROM weight_log ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
    client.query(query, (error, result) => {
      done();
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error });
      }
      if (result.rows < "1") {
        res.status(404).send({
          status: "Failed",
          message: "No weight information found"
        });
      } else {
        req.last = result.rows;
        console.log(result.rows);
        next();
      }
    });
  });
}

function renderMainPage(req, res) {
  res.render("index", {
    lastRecord: req.last
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your code though? The code does seem logical. What's the problem you want to solve?

Comment: @ionizer, yes code is working as it is, but my problem is I want to take json object from getLastRecord then format to value and then pass this value to new function which calculate BMI, Then when I got value I think I need change this value to json object and then pass to renderMainPage. Am I right? Am I follow right path?